How to make an Excel-like Clustered Column chart in TradingView Pine Script (version 5)?
I have an indicator that calculates (hopefully correctly) the percent and basis point change of a security (I use it for FX) by trading session (i.e., Tokyo, London, New York) per day of the week. This runs on an hourly time frame. I would like to display the %chg/bps chg in a clustered column excel like chart, where each day of the week would show 3 columns, one for each trading session, Monday to Friday, so a total of 3 colums per day multiplied by 5 trading days per week.
I suspect this is not possible in TV. I've tried my hand at using labels, but I've had no luck. Below is the current iteration of the code, and I'm sure there are mistakes; if so, feel free to point them out or correct them, too:
`
//@version=5
indicator("BPS Day of Week", overlay=false)
// Input for the number of weeks to average
numWeeks = input.int(defval=1, title="Number of Weeks to Average", minval=1, maxval=100000)

// Input to toggle between percentage or basis point display
displayMode = input.string(defval="Percentage", title="Display Mode", options=["Percentage", "Basis Points"])

// Get the hour for New York and London based on their respective timezones (handles DST automatically)
nyHour = hour(time, "America/New_York")
londonHour = hour(time, "Europe/London")
utcHour = hour(time, "Etc/UTC")  // UTC doesn't use DST

// Tokyo session (no DST adjustments needed)
tokyoSessionStart = 21  // Starts at 21:00 UTC
tokyoSessionEnd = 8     // Ends at 08:00 UTC

// Define the trading sessions using DST-aware logic
isTokyoSession = (utcHour >= tokyoSessionStart or utcHour < tokyoSessionEnd)  // 21:00 PM - 08:00     AM UTC
isLondonSession = (londonHour >= 7 and londonHour < 17)  // London: 7:00 AM - 5:00 PM local time
isNewYorkSession = (nyHour >= 7 and nyHour < 17)  // New York: 7:00 AM - 5:00 PM local time

// Define variables to store session open prices
var float sessionOpenPriceTokyo = na
var float sessionOpenPriceLondon = na
var float sessionOpenPriceNewYork = na

// Calculate percentage or basis point change
percentChange(openPrice, closePrice) =>
    (closePrice / openPrice - 1) * 100

basisPointChange(openPrice, closePrice) =>
    (closePrice - openPrice) * 10000

// Initialize arrays for each session and day of the week
var float[] tokyoChangesMonday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] londonChangesMonday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] newYorkChangesMonday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] tokyoChangesTuesday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] londonChangesTuesday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] newYorkChangesTuesday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] tokyoChangesWednesday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] londonChangesWednesday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] newYorkChangesWednesday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] tokyoChangesThursday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] londonChangesThursday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] newYorkChangesThursday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] tokyoChangesFriday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] londonChangesFriday = array.new_float(0)
var float[] newYorkChangesFriday = array.new_float(0)

// Store percentage or basis point change for each session by day of the week
storeSessionChange(dayArray, openPrice, closePrice) =>
    currentChange = displayMode == "Basis Points" ? basisPointChange(openPrice, closePrice) :  percentChange(openPrice, closePrice)
    if array.size(dayArray) >= numWeeks
        array.shift(dayArray)  // Remove oldest element
    array.push(dayArray, currentChange)

// Handle open price resets
if (isTokyoSession and not isTokyoSession[1])
    sessionOpenPriceTokyo := open
if (isLondonSession and not isLondonSession[1])
    sessionOpenPriceLondon := open
if (isNewYorkSession and not isNewYorkSession[1])
     sessionOpenPriceNewYork := open

// Handle the end of sessions (store session changes)
if (not isTokyoSession and isTokyoSession[1]) 
    if dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
        storeSessionChange(tokyoChangesMonday, sessionOpenPriceTokyo, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
        storeSessionChange(tokyoChangesTuesday, sessionOpenPriceTokyo, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
        storeSessionChange(tokyoChangesWednesday, sessionOpenPriceTokyo, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
        storeSessionChange(tokyoChangesThursday, sessionOpenPriceTokyo, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
        storeSessionChange(tokyoChangesFriday, sessionOpenPriceTokyo, close)


if (not isLondonSession and isLondonSession[1]) 
    if dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
        storeSessionChange(londonChangesMonday, sessionOpenPriceLondon, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
        storeSessionChange(londonChangesTuesday, sessionOpenPriceLondon, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
        storeSessionChange(londonChangesWednesday, sessionOpenPriceLondon, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
        storeSessionChange(londonChangesThursday, sessionOpenPriceLondon, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
        storeSessionChange(londonChangesFriday, sessionOpenPriceLondon, close)


if (not isNewYorkSession and isNewYorkSession[1]) 
    if dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
        storeSessionChange(newYorkChangesMonday, sessionOpenPriceNewYork, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
        storeSessionChange(newYorkChangesTuesday, sessionOpenPriceNewYork, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
        storeSessionChange(newYorkChangesWednesday, sessionOpenPriceNewYork, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
        storeSessionChange(newYorkChangesThursday, sessionOpenPriceNewYork, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
        storeSessionChange(newYorkChangesFriday, sessionOpenPriceNewYork, close)


// Function to calculate the average change per session for each day of the week
averageChange(changesArray) =>
    total = 0.0
    count = array.size(changesArray)
    if count > 0
        for i = 0 to count - 1
            total := total + array.get(changesArray, i)
        total / count
    else
        na

// Calculate averages for each day of the week
mondayTokyoAvg = averageChange(tokyoChangesMonday)
mondayLondonAvg = averageChange(londonChangesMonday)
mondayNewYorkAvg = averageChange(newYorkChangesMonday)
tuesdayTokyoAvg = averageChange(tokyoChangesTuesday)
tuesdayLondonAvg = averageChange(londonChangesTuesday)
tuesdayNewYorkAvg = averageChange(newYorkChangesTuesday)
wednesdayTokyoAvg = averageChange(tokyoChangesWednesday)
wednesdayLondonAvg = averageChange(londonChangesWednesday)
wednesdayNewYorkAvg = averageChange(newYorkChangesWednesday)
thursdayTokyoAvg = averageChange(tokyoChangesThursday)
thursdayLondonAvg = averageChange(londonChangesThursday)
thursdayNewYorkAvg = averageChange(newYorkChangesThursday)
fridayTokyoAvg = averageChange(tokyoChangesFriday)
fridayLondonAvg = averageChange(londonChangesFriday)
fridayNewYorkAvg = averageChange(newYorkChangesFriday)

// Use table.new to manually display averages in a table
var table columnTable = table.new(position.top_right, 4, 6, border_width=1)

// Update the table periodically
if bar_index % 1 == 0
    table.cell(columnTable, 0, 0, "Session", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.yellow)
    table.cell(columnTable, 1, 0, "Tokyo", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.red)
    table.cell(columnTable, 2, 0, "London", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.blue)
    table.cell(columnTable, 3, 0, "New York", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.green)

    table.cell(columnTable, 0, 1, "Monday Avg", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
    table.cell(columnTable, 1, 1, str.tostring(mondayTokyoAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.red)
    table.cell(columnTable, 2, 1, str.tostring(mondayLondonAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.blue)
    table.cell(columnTable, 3, 1, str.tostring(mondayNewYorkAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.green)

    table.cell(columnTable, 0, 2, "Tuesday Avg", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
    table.cell(columnTable, 1, 2, str.tostring(tuesdayTokyoAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.red)
    table.cell(columnTable, 2, 2, str.tostring(tuesdayLondonAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.blue)
    table.cell(columnTable, 3, 2, str.tostring(tuesdayNewYorkAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.green)

    table.cell(columnTable, 0, 3, "Wednesday Avg", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
    table.cell(columnTable, 1, 3, str.tostring(wednesdayTokyoAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.red)
    table.cell(columnTable, 2, 3, str.tostring(wednesdayLondonAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.blue)
    table.cell(columnTable, 3, 3, str.tostring(wednesdayNewYorkAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.green)

    table.cell(columnTable, 0, 4, "Thursday Avg", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
    table.cell(columnTable, 1, 4, str.tostring(thursdayTokyoAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.red)
    table.cell(columnTable, 2, 4, str.tostring(thursdayLondonAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.blue)
table.cell(columnTable, 3, 4, str.tostring(thursdayNewYorkAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.green)

    table.cell(columnTable, 0, 5, "Friday Avg", bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
    table.cell(columnTable, 1, 5, str.tostring(fridayTokyoAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.red)
    table.cell(columnTable, 2, 5, str.tostring(fridayLondonAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.blue)
    table.cell(columnTable, 3, 5, str.tostring(fridayNewYorkAvg, "#.##"), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.green)

// Display labels for each session and day
displayLabel(labelText, avgValue, colorValue) =>
    if not na(avgValue)  // Ensure the average value is valid
        label.new(time, avgValue, labelText, xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=label.style_label_down,          color=colorValue, textcolor=color.white)

// Day offsets for proper label positioning
dayOffset(day) =>
    if (day == dayofweek.monday)
        1
    else if (day == dayofweek.tuesday)
        2
    else if (day == dayofweek.wednesday)
        3
    else if (day == dayofweek.thursday)
        4
    else
        5  // Friday

// Display average values for each day of the week (one label per session per day)
if dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
    displayLabel("Tokyo (Mon)", mondayTokyoAvg, color.red)
    displayLabel("London (Mon)", mondayLondonAvg, color.blue)
    displayLabel("New York (Mon)", mondayNewYorkAvg, color.green)

if dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
    displayLabel("Tokyo (Tue)", tuesdayTokyoAvg, color.red)
    displayLabel("London (Tue)", tuesdayLondonAvg, color.blue)
    displayLabel("New York (Tue)", tuesdayNewYorkAvg, color.green)

if dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
    displayLabel("Tokyo (Wed)", wednesdayTokyoAvg, color.red)
    displayLabel("London (Wed)", wednesdayLondonAvg, color.blue)
    displayLabel("New York (Wed)", wednesdayNewYorkAvg, color.green)

if dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
    displayLabel("Tokyo (Thu)", thursdayTokyoAvg, color.red)
    displayLabel("London (Thu)", thursdayLondonAvg, color.blue)
    displayLabel("New York (Thu)", thursdayNewYorkAvg, color.green)

if dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
    displayLabel("Tokyo (Fri)", fridayTokyoAvg, color.red)
    displayLabel("London (Fri)", fridayLondonAvg, color.blue)
    displayLabel("New York (Fri)", fridayNewYorkAvg, color.green)

`
The target is to display one column for each trading session (Tokyo, London, New York) for each day of the week (Monday through Friday). That means a total of 15 columns, with three for each day.
Here is what has been tried:
Histogram Bars:
Approach: Started by plotting histogram bars (plot.style_histogram) to represent the average percentage or basis point change per session per day.
Outcome: The histograms appeared in each hourly bar on the chart, resulting in far too many columns. The issue here was that the script plotted columns at each interval rather than only once per day per session. We expected only 15 columns total, but the script plotted them at every hour.
Guess at why it failed: Pine Script updates on each bar, and since we’re working on hourly data, it plotted a column for each hour of the chart, not just once per session.
Label:
Approach: Next, tried using labels instead of histogram bars. The idea was to place labels for each session and day (Monday to Friday) at specific offsets, with custom text to represent the data.
Outcome: While the labels displayed, the issue persisted with too many labels being drawn—more than the expected 15. Additionally, labels still appeared at each hour, not just at the close of each session or day.
Guess at why it failed: There were issues with calculating the correct x-axis positions (label offsets), and the label-based method still drew excessive labels, as it was tied to each bar update rather than just once per day.
Manual Offsetting via Day of Week:
Approach: Incorporated logic to offset labels or columns based on the day of the week (e.g., Monday offset by 0, Tuesday by 5, etc.). This approach was designed to display three columns per day and avoid drawing them at every hour.
Outcome: Even with the dayofweek logic, we still faced issues with bar-index-based positioning. Pine Script’s limitation of displaying objects only within a specific range (500 bars forward or backward) led to errors when attempting to place objects too far from the current bar.
Guess at why it failed: The difficulty here was managing both x-positioning and bar indexing with Pine Script's constraints. Additionally, logic that controlled session handling (Tokyo, London, New York) still triggered more labels than desired, as it ran each time the script updated.
Using time for Label Positioning:
Approach: Tried to use the time function to control label positioning more accurately instead of relying on bar indices.
Outcome: The error of placing objects too far from the current bar persisted, and there were still too many labels, as the script continued drawing labels per hour rather than once per session or day.
Guess at why it failed: Pine Script has restrictions on placing objects too far in the future or past, and this approach still didn’t solve the issue of overdrawn labels. Furthermore, time function placement led to labels being placed incorrectly.
Root Cause of Failure:
The primary issue with all approaches is that Pine Script processes each bar independently and redraws based on every bar update. Because of using hourly intervals, it attempts to plot data for every hour, leading to too many labels or bars being drawn. The logic for session tracking (isTokyoSession, isLondonSession, etc.) runs on every hourly bar, triggering the display functions too frequently.
Additionally, there’s a complication with how Pine Script handles label positioning (label.new). It enforces strict rules about how far into the future or past a label can be drawn relative to the current bar, which conflicts with our needs to show a label for only one point per session per day.
Would custom shapes for the columns work?
